# Sync two audio files

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg, signal-processing, sox

I have 2 audio files:

- correct.wav (duration 3:07)
- incorrect.wav (duration 3:10)

[image: 2 audio files]

They are almost the same, but was generated with different sound fonts.

**The problem: The second file is late for a few seconds.**

How can I sync second file with the first one? Maybe there some bash software that could detect first loud sounds appearance in the first sound and compare correct.wav with incorrect.wav, shorten the end of the incorrect.wav file.

I know I can do it manually, but I need automated soulution for a lot of files.

Here is approximate solutions I found:

1) for detecting sound syncing to use this Python script - https://github.com/jeorgen/align-videos-by-sound but it's not perfect, not detecting 100%.

2) use sox for cutting/trimming/comparing/detecting sound durations (code extraction):

```
length1ok=$(sox correct.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p')
length2ok=$(sox incorrect.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p')
if [[ $length1ok == $length2ok ]]; then
    echo "Everything OK: $length1ok = $length2ok"
else
    echo "Fatal error: Not the same final files"
fi

diff=$(echo "$length2 - $length1" | bc -l)
echo "difference = $diff"
echo "webm $length1 not greater than fluid2 $length2"
sox correct.wav incorrect.wav pad 0 $diff
```

**Comment to UltrasoundJelly's answer:**
Here what result I get for your code:

[image: Result]

Here what result I need:

[image: Need result]

Comment: Will files have some silence at the start?

Comment: in most situations - yes, it depends on correct.wav file, the start silence could vary from 1-5 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution:

- Use `ffmpeg` to find the leading silence in each file
- If the new file has a longer leading silence, trim the difference with `sox`
- If the new file has a shorter leading silence, pad the start with `sox`
- Trim the new file to the same length as the original with `sox`

Bash Script:

```
FILEONE=$1
FILETWO=$2
MINSILENCE=0.1
THRESH="-50dB"
S1=$(ffmpeg -i $FILEONE -af silencedetect=noise=$THRESH:d=$MINSILENCE -f null -  2>&1 | grep silence_duration -m 1 | awk '{print $NF}')
S2=$(ffmpeg -i $FILETWO -af silencedetect=noise=$THRESH:d=$MINSILENCE -f null -  2>&1 | grep silence_duration -m 1 | awk '{print $NF}')
if [ -z "$S1" ]; then echo "no starting silence found in $FILEONE" && exit 1;fi
if [ -z "$S2" ]; then echo "no starting silence found in $FILETWO" && exit 1;fi
DIFF=$(echo "$S1-$S2"|bc)
ISNEG=$(echo $DIFF'>0'| bc -l)
DIFF=${DIFF#-}
BASE="${FILETWO%.*}"
if [ $ISNEG -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "$1>$2 ... padding $2"
  SAMPRATE=$(sox --i -r $FILETWO)
  sox -n -r $SAMPRATE -c 2 silence.wav trim 0.0 $DIFF
  sox silence.wav $FILETWO $BASE.shift.wav
  rm silence.wav
else
  echo "$1<$2 ... trimming $2"
  sox $FILETWO $BASE.trim.wav trim $DIFF
fi

length1=$(sox $FILEONE -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p')
length2=$(sox $BASE.trim.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p')

if (( $(echo "$length2 > $length1" | bc -l) )); then
    diff=$(echo "$length2 - $length1" | bc -l)
    echo "difference = $diff"
    sox $BASE.trim.wav finished.wav trim 0 -$diff
fi
```

Comment: Wow, it's almost what I need, but I updated my question with pictures what exactly I need. Please reply me.

Comment: will just need to trim the longer file.  i'll revamp the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll accept your answer after revamping. I've spent many hours manually editing hundreds of these files, with your help I could do it automatically)

Comment: It works like a charm. I've added some code to remove end of file FILETWO so FILEONE == FILETWO duration. Сode could be a bit messy, so you could edit it.

Comment: One other thing to mention, you might get even better precision if you first normalize the audio on each file before you run the code.  It looks like one of your files is significantly quieter than the other.

Comment: Thanks, I will check normalization on 2 files. First sound is very loud, so it has rustling. Normalization not helping to remove rustling, that's why I am using such complex way with 2 soundfonts. Also now I am working on situation if second file starting silence located before first file starting silence, now it outputs not correctly.

Comment: So, do you want to pad the second file instead of shortening the first?  I'll mod my code again.

Comment: There could be 2 different situations: pad and trim of second file. 50% of code works perfectly. The main mission: make sync with the first file starting silence location.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, now it works 100%, in padding situation it has "(standard_in) 1: parse error", I believe it's not critical "bc" error.